# How to use ALCameraViewController library in an Objective C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, camera

The documents say to use this in swift:

```
        let cameraViewController = CameraViewController { [weak self] image, asset in
        // Do something with your image here.
        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } 
present(cameraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I don't know how to convert this to Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

It's just clever looking code because he's got Swift default values in the initializer for CameraViewController. Objective-C does not support default values, so you need to provide them. The source is [right here](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController/blob/master/ALCameraViewController/ViewController/CameraViewController.swift#L162-L166).

Something like this:

croppingParameters: CroppingParameters = CroppingParameters(),
                allowsLibraryAccess: Bool = true,
                allowsSwapCameraOrientation: Bool = true,
                allowVolumeButtonCapture: Bool = true,
                completion: @escaping CameraViewCompletion

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
CameraViewController *cameraViewController = [[CameraViewController alloc] 
    initWithCroppingParameters:[CroppingParameters new]
    allowsLibraryAccess: YES
    allowsSwapCameraOrientation: YES
    allowVolumeButtonCapture: YES
    completion: ^(UIImage *image, PHAsset *asset) {
        [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

[self presentViewController:cameraViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But since the ALCamera project doesn't seem to care that much about Objective-C, there might not be full support for it.